# Is there any Vision Transformer + Text Transformer Model to to perform document classification on Labels(forms, agreements, invoices etc)

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

Would love to know your response.Just want to ask that if I am having images, text as inputs and their labels as form, agreement, invoices etc. How can I use Hugging face CLIP Model or is there any other model available?

I want to do Document Classification Task.

Comment: Can you please add some information regarding the data of have? Does the model needs to handle both text and image at the same time or is the input either text or image but never both?